# ClassNotFoundException after grails3 war deployment on tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I have troubles deploying my grails3 application to a tomcat7 server. In the local development environment (bundled tomcat-server) everything works well. The code compiles and runs.

Then I use `grails clean` and `grails war` to create war which I deployed to a tomcat7-instance. While starting tomcat it crashes with the following error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in ewsohelemeter.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EwsOhElemeter.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:120) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55) [grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57) [grails-web-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EwsOhElemeter.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EwsOhElemeter.Role
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.scanUsingPattern(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:142) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.classes(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:80) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:62) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Mar 13, 2016 2:58:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EwsOhElemeter-0.1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in ewsohelemeter.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EwsOhElemeter.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
    at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EwsOhElemeter.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EwsOhElemeter.Role
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.scanUsingPattern(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:142)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.classes(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:80)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 33 more

Mar 13, 2016 2:58:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/instance3/webapps/EwsOhElemeter-0.1.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EwsOhElemeter-0.1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem seems to be that the classloader could not find my spring-security role-domain `EwsOhElemeter.Role` which is definitely present. Also it works in my local environment.

Maybe its a classpath problem or some of the classes do not get compiled into the war file.

Steps I tried:
 - Changed integrated tomcat-instance from "compile" to "provided"
 - Cleaned build and grandle folders
 - A lot of `grails clean`

Comment: Where exactly did you put `EwsOhElemeter.Role` in your project path?

Comment: Where the domain class files should go – like this: http://i.imgur.com/RSbl3ha.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution: It seemed to be a problem with the package name. It contained some capital characters. Spring security seems to have problems with case sensitive package names. I converted all of them to lower case and tada: It works!

Thanks for the solution